# Record video from front facing camera during ARKit ARSession on iPhone X

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, arkit, iphone-x

I'm using an `ARSession` combined with an `ARFaceTrackingConfiguration` to track my face. At the same time, I would like to record a video from the front facing camera of my iPhone X. To do so I'm using `AVCaptureSession` but as soon as I start recording, the `ARSession` gets interrupted.

These are two snippets of code:

```
// Face tracking
let configuration = ARFaceTrackingConfiguration()
    configuration.isLightEstimationEnabled = false
let session = ARSession()
session.run(configuration, options: [.removeExistingAnchors, .resetTracking])

// Video recording
let camera = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .front)!
input = try! AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: camera)
session.addInput(input)
session.addOutput(output)
```

Does anybody know how to do the two things at the same time? Apps like Snapchat allow users to record and use the True Depth sensor at the same time so I imagine what I'm asking is perfectly feasible. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ARKit runs its own `AVCaptureSession`, and there can be only one capture session running at a time — if you run a capture session, you preempt ARKit’s, which prevents ARKit from working.

However, ARKit does provide access to the camera pixel buffers it receives from its capture session, so you can record video by feeding those sample buffers to an `AVAssetWriter`. (It’s basically the same workflow you’d use when recording video from `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`... a lower-level way of doing video recording compared to `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`.)

You can also feed the ARKit camera pixel buffers (see [`ARFrame.capturedImage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arframe/2867984-capturedimage)) to other technologies that work with live camera imagery, like the Vision framework. Apple has a [sample code project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/using_vision_in_real_time_with_arkit) demonstrating such usage.

Comment: Very good news. I will try it out asap and get back to you. Thank you Rick

Comment: hi rickster, the sample code project link is broken at the moment. Do you know if it has been moved somewhere else?

Comment: Edited post to fix links

Comment: @rickster - I did what you say to record video and audio from RealityKit and also from a capture device I am building with Arduino and the result is the same: video without audio. [This is a question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62937153/this-code-generates-videos-that-play-fine-but-play-without-audio-why) about that.