# Is it possible to run 2 independent ARSessions simultaneously?

Tags: swift, arkit, arscnview

Since ARKit3 it is possible to run a ARSession() that supports the back and front camera simultaneously.

For example this creates an ARConfiguration for the front camera that supports also Worldtracking.

```
    // session for the front camera
    let configuration = ARFaceTrackingConfiguration()
    configuration.isWorldTrackingEnabled
    sceneView.session.run(configuration)
```

This example creates a configuration for a back camera session with Face Tracking enabled:

```
    // session for the back camera
    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    configuration.userFaceTrackingEnabled = true
    sceneView.session.run(configuration)
```

I would like to create 2 independent ARConfigurations and ARSessions that run simultaneously. Like this:

[image]

So far i tried this code:

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit
import ARKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {

// back camera view
@IBOutlet var backView: ARSCNView!

// front camera view
@IBOutlet weak var frontView: ARSCNView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Set the view's delegate
    sceneView.delegate = self
    frontView.delegate = self

    // Create a new scene for back camera
    let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!
    backView.scene = scene
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // session for the back camera
    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    configuration.userFaceTrackingEnabled = true
    backView.session.run(configuration)

    // session for the front camera
    guard ARFaceTrackingConfiguration.isSupported else { return }
    let configurationFront = ARFaceTrackingConfiguration()
    configurationFront.isLightEstimationEnabled = true
    frontView.session.run(configurationFront, options: [])
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    // Pause the view's session
    sceneView.session.pause()
}

func session(_ session: ARSession, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    // Present an error message to the user
}

func sessionWasInterrupted(_ session: ARSession) {
    // Inform the user that the session has been interrupted, for example, by presenting an overlay
}

func sessionInterruptionEnded(_ session: ARSession) {
    // Reset tracking and/or remove existing anchors if consistent tracking is required
}
}
```

The back camera stops its video feed while the front camera is working properly. Any chances to solve this ?

It would also be a solution to run one ARSession and one low level video capture session on the other camera but i am running into the same problems.

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50954987/3241041

Comment: Yes, thanks. That is basically the same problem. I will have a look at it.

Comment: So i had a look. This is a solution when you have only one active camera.
I would need to have both cameras active.